# RegExp split a string by its middle character matches

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'd like to split all the instances of a character that aren't the starting or ending character. For example: `"go good golly gog".split(RegExp)` would go to `["go ","ood ","olly ","og"]`.

Is this RegExp possible?

Comment: Its splitting all instances of the character, except the starting/ending matches.

Comment: Never mind I got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
"go good golly gog".split(/(?!^)g(?!$)/)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I figured out the second lookahead, but how does the first lookahead work? I thought you would have to use a negative lookbehind.

Comment: @Azmisov Yeah I would think it'd be "go good golly gog".split(/(?<!^)g(?!$)/)

Comment: @YGomez, lookbehind doesn't work in Javascript. And @Azmisov, I have to admit I'm slightly puzzled myself! :) It appears that (?!^) behaves like (?<!^) in Javascript. "12345".replace(/(?!^)12/, "ab") == "12345"; "12345".replace(/(?!1)23/, "ab") == "1ab45"

Comment: Aha! Silly me coming from the Perl camp thinking it's all the same :P