# Why is (?!^) equivalent to (?<!^)?

Tags: regex

A little while back I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448461/regexp-split-a-string-by-its-middle-character-matches) on SO, but I still haven't figured out why my answer worked.

For some reason, a negative lookahead for the start of a string behaves the same as a negative lookbehind.

For example, in PHP

```
preg_replace("/(?!^)12/", "ab", "12345");   // 12345
preg_replace("/(?<!^)12/", "ab", "12345");  // 12345
preg_replace("/(?!1)23/", "ab", "12345");   // 1ab45
preg_replace("/(?<!1)23/", "ab", "12345");  // 12345
```

I know it's not the most useful question ever asked, but this has been nagging me for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The caret is a zero-width assertion.  In fact lookaheads and lookbehinds are zero-width as well.  Therefore, in this case it doesn't matter if you're looking ahead or behind, you're still looking at the same character position.

This is explained pretty well in [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).